# Will an ASUS AC1900 be a good VPN server solution for remote Android & PC access?

Tags: linux, vpn, android, window

I want a VPN server for home.  I want to be able to remote in via Android, PC (Windows & Linux) for access.  Is this possible with the AC1900?  Thank you :)

Comment: It is possible with the AC1900. The motherboard really makes no difference if it will or not work for a VPN server. If it will work well is an opinion and opinion based questions are off topic here.

Comment: I needed this setup to work with Playstation Vue.  I tried it.  It works perfectly!  Not sure why it got down voted.  I wished for a better first experience here. I used Open vpn btw with a tcp connection.

Answer (score 0):

Reread the TOS as products are not allowed in a question.  With that said, I got one.  Set it up.  Enabled OpenVPN and then tcp.  It worked perfectly!  Quite happy with the result :)